# Incrementing 'self' variables within a class

Tags: python, oop, format, increment

I created a GUI that has many checkboxes for the user to click for options (about 28 but 7 for this example).
Instead of writing it all out manually, I would like to create a loop where it auto-increments the name of the checkboxes. I think the issue comes up when I am messing with the 'self' variable.

I want to turn this:

```
if self.checkboard01.get() ==1:
    self.counter01 = self.counter01 + 1
    board_num = 0
    channel = 1
    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
    self.mcc_list01.append(self.mcc_temp)
    self.time_list01.append(self.counter01)
    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =8, column = 4)
    self.plot()

if self.checkboard02.get() ==1:
    self.counter02 = self.counter02 + 1
    board_num = 0
    channel = 2
    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
    self.mcc_list02.append(self.mcc_temp)
    self.time_list02.append(self.counter02)
    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =9, column = 4)
    self.plot()

if self.checkboard03.get() ==1:
    self.counter03 = self.counter03 + 1
    board_num = 0
    channel = 3
    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
    self.mcc_list03.append(self.mcc_temp)
    self.time_list03.append(self.counter03)
    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =10, column = 4)
    self.plot()
```

Into something like this so I can create function:

But this results in an error "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

```
for a in range(0,8):
    for e in range(7,15):
        if '{}'.format(self.checkboard0 + a).get() ==1:
            '{}'.format(self.counter0 + a) = '{}'.format(self.counter0 + a) + 1
            board_num = 0
            channel = a
            self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
            self.mcc_list0a.append(self.mcc_temp)
            '{}'.format(self.time_list0+a).append('{}'.format(self.counter0+a))
            self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =e, column = 4)
            self.plot()
```

Full GUI Code:

```
import tkinter
from mcculw import ul
from mcculw.enums import TempScale
from mcculw.enums import InterfaceType
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class TempLogger:

    def __init__(self, window):

        window.title("TempLogger")


##### Create Board Labels

        tkinter.Label(window, text = "Board #0",font=("", 20), padx = 75).grid(row =4, column = 4)
        tkinter.Label(window, text = "Board #1",font=("", 20), padx = 75).grid(row =4, column = 7)
        tkinter.Label(window, text = "Board #2",font=("", 20), padx = 75).grid(row =4, column = 10)
        tkinter.Label(window, text = "Board #3",font=("", 20), padx = 75).grid(row =4, column = 13)

##### Create Enable checkboxes  

        self.checkboard0 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard1 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard2 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard3 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.en1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard0, text = 'Enable',font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).grid(row = 5, column = 4)
        self.en2 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard1, text = 'Enable',font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).grid(row = 5, column = 7)
        self.en3 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard2, text = 'Enable',font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).grid(row = 5, column = 10)
        self.en4 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard3, text = 'Enable',font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0).grid(row = 5, column = 13)

####### Create Channel labels

        for a in range(4,14,3):
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "Temp (C)",font=("", 12), pady = 15).grid(row =6, column = a)

        for e in range(3,13,3):
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "CH",font=("", 12), pady = 15).grid(row =6, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "0",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =7, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "1",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =8, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "2",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =9, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "3",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =10, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "4",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =11, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "5",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =12, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "6",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =13, column = e)
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "7",font=("", 12), pady = 25).grid(row =14, column = e)

###### Create checkboxes for channels

        self.checkboard00 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard01 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard02 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard03 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard04 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard05 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard06 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard07 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard10 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard11 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard12 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard13 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard14 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard15 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard16 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard17 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard20 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard21 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard22 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard23 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard24 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard25 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard26 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard27 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard30 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard31 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard32 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard33 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard34 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard35 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard36 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard37 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.ch00 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard00,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 7, column = 5)
        self.ch01 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard01,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 8, column = 5)
        self.ch02 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard02,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 9, column = 5)
        self.ch03 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard03,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 10, column = 5)
        self.ch04 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard04,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 11, column = 5)
        self.ch05 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard05,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 12, column = 5)
        self.ch06 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard06,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 13, column = 5)
        self.ch07 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard07,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 14, column = 5)
        self.ch10 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard10,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 7, column = 8)
        self.ch11 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard11,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 8, column = 8)
        self.ch12 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard12,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 9, column = 8)
        self.ch13 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard13,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 10, column = 8)
        self.ch14 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard14,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 11, column = 8)
        self.ch15 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard15,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 12, column = 8)
        self.ch16 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard16,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 13, column = 8)
        self.ch17 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard17,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 14, column = 8)
        self.ch20 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard20,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 7, column = 11)
        self.ch21 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard21,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 8, column = 11)
        self.ch22 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard22,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 9, column = 11)
        self.ch23 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard23,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 10, column = 11)
        self.ch24 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard24,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 11, column = 11)
        self.ch25 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard25,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 12, column = 11)
        self.ch26 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard26,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 13, column = 11)
        self.ch27 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard27,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 14, column = 11)
        self.ch30 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard30,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 7, column = 14)
        self.ch31 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard31,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 8, column = 14)
        self.ch32 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard32,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 9, column = 14)
        self.ch33 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard33,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 10, column = 14)
        self.ch34 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard34,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 11, column = 14)
        self.ch34 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard35,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 12, column = 14)
        self.ch36 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard36,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 13, column = 14)
        self.ch37 = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable = self.checkboard37,font=("", 12), onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, padx = 10, pady = 10).grid(row = 14, column = 14)

##### Create temperature placeholders

        for a in range(7,15):
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "",bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 170).grid(row =a, column = 4)

        for e in range(7,15):
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "",bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 170).grid(row =e, column = 7)

        for i in range(7,15):
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "",bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 170).grid(row =i, column = 10)

        for o in range(7,15):
            tkinter.Label(window, text = "",bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 170).grid(row =o, column = 13)

###### Create Start/Stop/Clear

        self.start_btn = tkinter.Button(window, text = "START", font=('', 12), fg = 'green', command = self.start).grid(row = 15, column = 7) 
        self.stop_btn = tkinter.Button(window, text = "STOP", font=('', 12), fg = 'red', command = self.stop).grid(row = 15, column = 8)
        self.clear_btn = tkinter.Button(window, text = "Clear Plot", font=('', 12), fg = 'red', command = self.clear).grid(row = 15, column = 4)

        tkinter.Label(window, text = 'Refresh rate in seconds',font=("", 12), padx = 30).grid(row = 15, column = 10)
        self.refresh_var = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.refresh = tkinter.Entry(window, text = 'Refresh rate in seconds', font = ('', 12), textvariable = self.refresh_var, width = 3, bg = "burlywood").grid(row = 15, column = 11)

###### Create empty lists for plotting    

        self.counter00 = -1    
        self.mcc_list00, self.time_list00 = [], []
        self.counter01 = -1    
        self.mcc_list01, self.time_list01 = [], []
        self.counter02 = -1    
        self.mcc_list02, self.time_list02 = [], []
        self.counter03 = -1    
        self.mcc_list03, self.time_list03 = [], []
        self.counter04 = -1    
        self.mcc_list04, self.time_list04 = [], []
        self.counter05 = -1    
        self.mcc_list05, self.time_list05 = [], []
        self.counter06 = -1    
        self.mcc_list06, self.time_list06 = [], []
        self.counter07 = -1    
        self.mcc_list07, self.time_list07 = [], []
        self.counter10 = -1    
        self.mcc_list10, self.time_list10 = [], []
        self.counter11 = -1    
        self.mcc_list11, self.time_list11 = [], []
        self.counter12 = -1    
        self.mcc_list12, self.time_list12 = [], []
        self.counter13 = -1    
        self.mcc_list13, self.time_list13 = [], []
        self.counter14 = -1    
        self.mcc_list14, self.time_list14 = [], []
        self.counter15 = -1    
        self.mcc_list15, self.time_list15 = [], []
        self.counter16 = -1    
        self.mcc_list16, self.time_list16 = [], []
        self.counter17 = -1    
        self.mcc_list17, self.time_list17 = [], []
        self.counter20 = -1    
        self.mcc_list20, self.time_list20 = [], []
        self.counter21 = -1    
        self.mcc_list21, self.time_list21 = [], []
        self.counter22 = -1    
        self.mcc_list22, self.time_list22 = [], []
        self.counter23 = -1    
        self.mcc_list23, self.time_list23 = [], []
        self.counter24 = -1    
        self.mcc_list24, self.time_list24 = [], []
        self.counter25 = -1    
        self.mcc_list25, self.time_list25 = [], []
        self.counter26 = -1    
        self.mcc_list26, self.time_list26 = [], []
        self.counter27 = -1    
        self.mcc_list27, self.time_list27 = [], []
        self.counter30 = -1    
        self.mcc_list30, self.time_list30 = [], []
        self.counter31 = -1    
        self.mcc_list31, self.time_list31 = [], []
        self.counter32 = -1    
        self.mcc_list32, self.time_list32 = [], []
        self.counter33 = -1    
        self.mcc_list33, self.time_list33 = [], []
        self.counter34 = -1    
        self.mcc_list34, self.time_list34 = [], []
        self.counter35 = -1    
        self.mcc_list35, self.time_list35 = [], []
        self.counter36 = -1    
        self.mcc_list36, self.time_list36 = [], []
        self.counter37 = -1    
        self.mcc_list37, self.time_list37 = [], []
        self.lgd = []

###### Create Setup functions

    def start(self):
        self.stop_button = 'False'
        self.flow()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_button = 'True'
        return self.stop_button

    def clear(self):
        self.counter00 = -1    
        self.mcc_list00, self.time_list00 = [], []
        self.counter01 = -1    
        self.mcc_list01, self.time_list01 = [], []
        self.counter02 = -1    
        self.mcc_list02, self.time_list02 = [], []
        self.counter03 = -1    
        self.mcc_list03, self.time_list03 = [], []
        self.counter04 = -1    
        self.mcc_list04, self.time_list04 = [], []
        self.counter05 = -1    
        self.mcc_list05, self.time_list05 = [], []
        self.counter06 = -1    
        self.mcc_list06, self.time_list06 = [], []
        self.counter07 = -1    
        self.mcc_list07, self.time_list07 = [], []
        self.counter10 = -1    
        self.mcc_list10, self.time_list10 = [], []
        self.counter11 = -1    
        self.mcc_list11, self.time_list11 = [], []
        self.counter12 = -1    
        self.mcc_list12, self.time_list12 = [], []
        self.counter13 = -1    
        self.mcc_list13, self.time_list13 = [], []
        self.counter14 = -1    
        self.mcc_list14, self.time_list14 = [], []
        self.counter15 = -1    
        self.mcc_list15, self.time_list15 = [], []
        self.counter16 = -1    
        self.mcc_list16, self.time_list16 = [], []
        self.counter17 = -1    
        self.mcc_list17, self.time_list17 = [], []
        self.counter20 = -1    
        self.mcc_list20, self.time_list20 = [], []
        self.counter21 = -1    
        self.mcc_list21, self.time_list21 = [], []
        self.counter22 = -1    
        self.mcc_list22, self.time_list22 = [], []
        self.counter23 = -1    
        self.mcc_list23, self.time_list23 = [], []
        self.counter24 = -1    
        self.mcc_list24, self.time_list24 = [], []
        self.counter25 = -1    
        self.mcc_list25, self.time_list25 = [], []
        self.counter26 = -1    
        self.mcc_list26, self.time_list26 = [], []
        self.counter27 = -1    
        self.mcc_list27, self.time_list27 = [], []
        self.counter30 = -1    
        self.mcc_list30, self.time_list30 = [], []
        self.counter31 = -1    
        self.mcc_list31, self.time_list31 = [], []
        self.counter32 = -1    
        self.mcc_list32, self.time_list32 = [], []
        self.counter33 = -1    
        self.mcc_list33, self.time_list33 = [], []
        self.counter34 = -1    
        self.mcc_list34, self.time_list34 = [], []
        self.counter35 = -1    
        self.mcc_list35, self.time_list35 = [], []
        self.counter36 = -1    
        self.mcc_list36, self.time_list36 = [], []
        self.counter37 = -1    
        self.mcc_list37, self.time_list37 = [], []


    def config_first_detected_device(self, board_num):
        devices = ul.get_daq_device_inventory(InterfaceType.ANY)
        if len(devices) > 0:
            device = devices[0]
            ul.create_daq_device(board_num, device)
            return True
        return False

    def getTempMcc(self, board_num, channel):
        board_num = board_num
        channel = channel
        try:
            self.config_first_detected_device(board_num)
            value = ul.t_in(board_num, channel, TempScale.CELSIUS)
            return value
        finally:
            ul.release_daq_device(board_num)

    def plot (self):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(20,8))
        a = fig.add_subplot(111)
        graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master = window)
        graph.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 18, column = 2,columnspan = 18, rowspan = 18, padx = 18)
        a.set_title ("Temperature Graph", fontsize=16)
        a.set_ylabel("Temp (C)", fontsize=14)
        a.set_xlabel("Time (sec)", fontsize=14)

        if self.checkboard00.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list00, self.mcc_list00, label = '00')

        if self.checkboard01.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list01, self.mcc_list01, label = '01')

        if self.checkboard02.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list02, self.mcc_list02, label = '02')

        if self.checkboard03.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list03, self.mcc_list03, label = '03')

        if self.checkboard04.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list04, self.mcc_list04, label = '04')

        if self.checkboard05.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list05, self.mcc_list05, label = '05')

        if self.checkboard06.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list06, self.mcc_list06, label = '06')

        if self.checkboard07.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list07, self.mcc_list07, label = '07')

        if self.checkboard10.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list10, self.mcc_list10, label = '10')

        if self.checkboard11.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list11, self.mcc_list11, label = '11')

        if self.checkboard12.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list12, self.mcc_list12, label = '12')

        if self.checkboard13.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list13, self.mcc_list13, label = '13')

        if self.checkboard14.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list14, self.mcc_list14, label = '14')

        if self.checkboard15.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list15, self.mcc_list15, label = '15')

        if self.checkboard16.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list16, self.mcc_list16, label = '16')

        if self.checkboard17.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list17, self.mcc_list17, label = '17')

        if self.checkboard20.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list20, self.mcc_list20, label = '20')

        if self.checkboard21.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list21, self.mcc_list21, label = '21')

        if self.checkboard22.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list22, self.mcc_list22, label = '22')

        if self.checkboard23.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list23, self.mcc_list23, label = '23')

        if self.checkboard24.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list24, self.mcc_list24, label = '24')

        if self.checkboard25.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list25, self.mcc_list25, label = '25')

        if self.checkboard26.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list26, self.mcc_list26, label = '26')

        if self.checkboard27.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list27, self.mcc_list27, label = '27')

        if self.checkboard30.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list30, self.mcc_list30, label = '30')

        if self.checkboard31.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list31, self.mcc_list31, label = '31')

        if self.checkboard32.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list32, self.mcc_list32, label = '32')

        if self.checkboard33.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list33, self.mcc_list33, label = '33')

        if self.checkboard34.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list34, self.mcc_list34, label = '34')

        if self.checkboard35.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list35, self.mcc_list35, label = '35')

        if self.checkboard36.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list36, self.mcc_list36, label = '36')

        if self.checkboard37.get() ==1:
            a.plot(self.time_list37, self.mcc_list37, label = '37')

        a.legend(loc = 'upper right')
        graph.draw()


#### Create executing function

    def flow(self):
        if self.stop_button == 'False':

            if self.checkboard0.get() == 1:

                if self.checkboard00.get() ==1:
                    self.counter00 = self.counter00 + 1
                    board_num = 0
                    channel = 0
                    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
                    self.mcc_list00.append(self.mcc_temp)
                    self.time_list00.append(self.counter00)
                    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
                    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =7, column = 4)
                    self.plot()

                if self.checkboard01.get() ==1:
                    self.counter01 = self.counter01 + 1
                    board_num = 0
                    channel = 1
                    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
                    self.mcc_list01.append(self.mcc_temp)
                    self.time_list01.append(self.counter01)
                    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
                    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =8, column = 4)
                    self.plot()

                if self.checkboard02.get() ==1:
                    self.counter02 = self.counter02 + 1
                    board_num = 0
                    channel = 2
                    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
                    self.mcc_list02.append(self.mcc_temp)
                    self.time_list02.append(self.counter02)
                    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
                    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =9, column = 4)
                    self.plot()

                if self.checkboard03.get() ==1:
                    self.counter03 = self.counter03 + 1
                    board_num = 0
                    channel = 3
                    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
                    self.mcc_list03.append(self.mcc_temp)
                    self.time_list03.append(self.counter03)
                    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
                    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =10, column = 4)
                    self.plot()

                if self.checkboard04.get() ==1:
                    self.counter04 = self.counter04 + 1
                    board_num = 0
                    channel = 4
                    self.mcc_temp = self.getTempMcc(board_num, channel)
                    self.mcc_list04.append(self.mcc_temp)
                    self.time_list04.append(self.counter04)
                    self.mcc_temp = round(self.mcc_temp, 2)
                    tkinter.Label(window, text = self.mcc_temp,bg = 'burlywood',font=("", 12), padx = 120).grid(row =11, column = 4)
                    self.plot()
        window.after(int(self.refresh_var.get()) *1, self.flow)

window = tkinter.Tk()
templogger = TempLogger(window)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `self`. The expression `'{}'.format(self.counter0 + a) = '{}'.format(self.counter0 + a) + 1` results in a `str` object. It makes no sense to assign to a string object to begin with, furthermore, the *compiler* actually catches that you are trying to assign to a function call, which similarly makes no sense. You probably just want `getattr` and `setattr`, to dynamically retrieve/set an attribute using a strin, so `attribute = 'counter0'+a` then `setattr(self, attribute, getattr(self, attribute) + 1)`

Comment: I am having trouble following. I'm still learning python at the moment. I replaced what you suggested with I had but now I am having issues with the expression: `'{}'.format(self.checkboard0 + a).get() ==1`

Comment: @Nycbros What is that expression? I don’t think that makes much sense. What do you think `.format()` does, exactly? Also, can you share the entirety of your program?

Comment: I was thinking that format was used kind of like declaring a variable. Before that expression I had: `if self.checkboard03.get() ==1:` where I would get the Boolean value of the checkbox. I even tried `'self.checkboard0{}'.format(a).get() ==1`

Comment: @Nycbros no, `.format` formats a `str` object. And since `str` objects don't have a `.get()` method, it will throw an error. `str` objects *are not source code*. And you shouldn't be dynamically generating code for this sort of thing to begin with. Note, Python *doesn't have variable declarations*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Now I understand. Thanks for the quick clarification on formatting. But I am still a bit confused on the suggestion you made.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile There are a lot of lines in my code for creating the GUI. are there parts you specifically want to look at?

Comment: I guess another way of asking my question is how do I get to increment 00, 01,02 with a loop? : `self.checkboard00 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard01 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard02 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard03 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard04 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard05 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard06 = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard07 = tkinter.IntVar()`

Comment: @Nycbros I was planning on at least refactoring the current code a bit, so I was just curious as to what the rest of the program looks like.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile updated...

Comment: @Nycbros Good lord that’s a ton of code. Does it all go into the same file? The goal is to be able to run the program.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile yeah all in one file. Like I said still learning :) I'm sure this is a way more efficient way in writing this

Comment: @Nycbros Should I copy/paste the code in the same order as in your post? Don’t worry, nothing wrong with being a beginner :) I’ll give it a shot

Comment: yeah. I had to cutout some imports because I reached my limit in character count

Comment: @Nycbros Oh that’s funny lol. You can mention them here if you want.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I updated it again. This time the bottom piece is gone. `window = tkinter.Tk()
templogger = TempLogger(window)
window.mainloop()`

Comment: @AlexanderCécile one last update. now you should be able to just copy and paste and run :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203710/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-nycbros).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to name your variables `self.checkboard01`, `self.checkboard01`, etc. Instead, store them in a list or dictionary. Then it becomes trivial to iterate over the values. This gives you one variable with 38 values rather than 38 distinct variables, making your code much easier to understand.

Since you're creating a checkerboard, using a dictionary with the row and column makes the most sense. With that, your function can look something like this:

```
for a in range(0,8):
    for e in range(7,15):
        widget = self.checkboard[(a,e)]
        value = checkbutton.get()
        ...
```

This also has the advantage of letting you create your 38 widgets far fewer lines of code:

```
self.checkboard = {}
self.vars = {}
for a in range(0, 8):
    for e in range(7,15):
        vars[(a,e)] = tkinter.IntVar()
        self.checkboard[(a,e)] = tkinter.Checkbutton(..., variable=vars[(a,e)])
```

Changing the number of buttons or changing the configuration of the buttons means you only have to change one or two lines rather than dozens.

Note: there's nothing special about using `(a,e)` as the key. If you prefer to use a string like `"checkerboard00"`, you can do that as well:

```
for a in range(0, 8):
    for e in range(7,15):
        key = "checkerboard%s%s" % (a,e)
        self.checkeboard[key] = ...
```

You can then use `self.checkerboard["checkerboard00"]` to get the upperleft corner. For me, using a tuple is a bit easier to use than building up an encoded string. The point is to use a dictionary, a be consistent with how you define the key.

Comment: This makes so much sense to me!

Comment: I can follow how to create a dictionary now but how can I call it or use it. Lets say I wanted the value from checkboard05?

Comment: @Nycbros: I don't know how you map `checkerboard05` to a row and column coordinate. The point is, use whatever indexing makes sense for you, then use that same index everywhere: `self.checkboard[(5,5)]` or `self.checkerboard['55']` or whatever makes the most sense.

Comment: I guess the issue I am having is getting the input value from the check box. I have `self.check_vars[(0,a)] = tkinter.IntVar()                                   
                self.checkboard[(0,a)] = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, variable=self.check_vars[0,a]).grid(row = e, column = 5)`                           How do I index checkboard00... like this: `self.check_vars[0,0].get()` or `self.check_vars[(0,0)].get()`

Comment: @Nycbros If you create `self.check_vars[(0,1)]`, then to get the value you use `self.check_vars[(0,a)].get()`. You're over-thinking the problem. The point is, use a dictionary, and for the key use a unique identifier. You can use `(0,a)` or `"checkbutton00"` or anything else. To me, using a tuple of `(row, column)` makes sense, but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. Got it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I haven't work on my code for a bit. I am able to index as needed from your help. In my Gui, when I try to 'check' a checkbox, it doesn't seem to update my "IntVar" variable. Whether I check it or uncheck it, it always returns '0' as if it is never 'checked'. Is there an update method or something similar?

Comment: @Nycbros: I can't answer that in a comment. When done properly, checking the checkbox either with the mouse or through the `select` or `deselect` methods, the variable will automatically get updated. That's precisely what they are designed to do.

Comment: Even within a dictionary?

Comment: @Nycbros: yes, if I understand you correctly, and the dictionary defines instances of `IntVar`. The fact they are in a dictionary doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Well I have some debugging to do then. Thanks again.